# Find roots of polynomial $f(X) = X^7 - 6 X^6 + 10 X^5 - 13 X^3 + 18 X^2 -22 X + 12 \in \mathbb Q[X]$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find the roots of the polynomial

$$
  f(X) = X^7 - 6  X^6 + 10X^5 - 13  X^3 + 18  X^2 -22  X + 12 \in \mathbb Q[X]
$$

in $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$.

We covered the factor-theorem in the lectures but I dont know how to apply it to this task, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial is monic, so for the rational roots you must search through the divisors of 12, the 0-degree term. By sostituion, you find that 1,2 and 3 are the rational roots. Making the polynomial division of $f(x)$ by $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ you find a four-degree polynomial, that decomposes as $(x^2+1)(x^2-2)$, and you have the other roots.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Evaluate $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$. What does the factor-theorem tell you?

**Further hint:** You are now left with a quartic polynomial, which is easy to divide. Otherwise, find $f( \sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Sorry Calvin, i hadn't seen your reply

Comment: @LecSka No worries. I intentionally didn't want to elaborate too much. I decided against talking about rational root theorem, since OP only mentioned factor-theorem. It's possible that he hasn't covered that yet, and 'should only be using factor-theorem for now'.